# how to find the order of elements in array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sorting

If I have an array of `A = [10 1 5 20]` I want a program to find indexes of the elements. In this case `Idx = [3 1 2 4]`. I am using `[~,Idx]=sort([10 1 5 20])` and get the following:

```
Idx =
        
    2     3     1     4
```

It's totally not what I expected. I even don't understand how the program got those numbers.

Comment: This is expected. The smallest value in your array is 1, and is located at index 2 in the original array. Therefore 2 is the first value in Idx. The second smallest value is 5, and is located at index 3 in your original array. Therefore the next value in Idx is 3. And so on. What are you trying to achieve / would like to see?

Comment: You say it's totally not what you expected. So you should say what you expected [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple:

```
A = [10 1 5 20];
[~, Idx] = sort(A);
[~, orders] = sort(Idx);

% orders
% [3 1 2 4]
```

`orders` is your answer. You need to get the indices of sorted `Idx`.

Note that `Idx(i)` represents the index of `i-th` element in the original array `A`.